# building javascript-consumable web services in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2013

Long-time .NET 2.0 developer, but a little rusty on the new web services the kids are running around with today. I'm building a new ASP.NET 4.5.1 intranet app and need to wrap my mundane ADO.NET data-access-layer of CRUD functions in web services that allow it to be consumed by JavaScript functions on the client-side. It's my understanding that REST is preferred over SOAP for new stuff.

Does Visual Studio 2013 have good projects for this? Does someone have a good guide or link to learning this in VS?

if it's relevant, all my BAL and app code is .NET 4.5.1, SQL Server back-end, and the current task is for facebook-style notifications -- alerts of new notifications, flagging notices as read, etc.

Comment: Look into http://www.asp.net/web-api - the latest and the greatest. And yes VS 2013 is perfect for that. The basic tutorial http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api walks your thru all the steps of creating service and consuming it on the client

Comment: thanks! that tutorial is great. running thru it now. 

question -- when writing your \Models classes (ex: Product.cs), is this your *main* business object class? for instance i have a fully-fleshed out Product.cs business object that has all my properties and methods and constructors and static methods on it...should i use that for the Models\Product.cs, or should Models\Product.cs be a slimmed down model of the product for API-use only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using VS 2013, you are already in a great place to begin the transition to RESTful services.  Just start a new "Web Application" project, and in 2013, you'll get a secondary set of options. Select "Web API" and you have all you need to get started.

Next setup your Web Api controllers to implement "ApiController" and start adding your GET, POST, PUT, etc methods that are accessed by using those verbs against the endpoint you created.

Start here for a sample or two... http://www.asp.net/web-api  For a quick overview, there's a free overview from [pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=jon-flanders&name=aspnetwebapi-m1-introduction&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspnetwebapi).  I personally made the transition using some of their paid courses, which were totally worth the subscription, but that's me, you may learn differently.

As for alerts and potential for cross site requests, look up CORS and SignalR samples there, both of which are easily integrated into 4.5.1 apps.

Comment: thanks! when writing your \Models classes (ex: Product.cs), is this your main business object class? for instance i have fully-fleshed out BAL object classes, like "Product.cs" that has all my properties, constructors, public & private methods, etc in it...should i use that for the Models\Product.cs, or should Models\Product.cs be a slimmed down model of the product for API-use only?

Comment: It depends of course, you'll still want to set up some models for collections of objects that may be presented from your response.  If you have enough time, you'd have separate objects that easily manage changes.  For Example, if you allow updates to your Product object, allowing a PUT that updates the created date/time stamp would be bad, so you'd want to have a validation somewhere, maybe have a trimmed down object for whatever you need to edit, maybe your BAL objects are "fully-fleshed" to the point that they can manage any changes or partial posts/puts.

Comment: thanks. to start ill probably go w/ a minimum API object that has methods only for the API-driven actions, which in turn call the main BAL objects (which are pretty heavy). im sure we'll figure it all out in time.

Answer (score 0):

REST != SOAP at all. REST embraces the http protocol and soap embraces remote procedure call style communications and all the soapy header stuff. You can be RESTful via WCF (which is what it sounds like what you are eluding to) but Web API is a natural fit \ successor of web services \ soapy like communications.

Here is the official web api link:

http://www.asp.net/web-api

And a getting started:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: -1: SOAP is not at all restricted to RPC style. And "natural successor" ignores all of the benefits you _lose_ by using Web API. The OP is coming from a .NET 2.0 background, so you do him no service by skipping right past the features of WCF.

Comment: @John WebApi has a easier learning curve than WCF. Also, I didn't say it was restricted to RPC style I said it embraces it. You can fake the funk with web services but until they had the WebHttpBinding class available (which came out after 2.0 in 3.5) you had to really understand how the bindings worked in WCF under the hood to achieve a RESTful-like service (by messing with BasicHttpBinding). So how can I assume the OP is familiar to the new binding \ usage when he is not familiar web api (or REST \ SOAP for that matter)?

Comment: So I don't think recommending Web API to a guy who is asking for a path to be able to request RESTful like stuff via javascript is a stretch or a disservice when WCF could very well end up confusing him.

Comment: "Learning curve?" That's total BS. A simple WCF service is trivial to do. And WCF didn't exist in .NET 2.0 - it came out with 3.5. And you could _never_ create anything like a RESTful service from basicHttpBinding. In fact, I think you're using the term "REST" to mean "using JSON". Maybe also "using routes"?

Comment: @John I wasn't being as clear as I should have and was going off memory BUT now that I have my book in front of me I can tell you more precisely what I meant: WCF came out with 3.0 actually and before 3.5 there was no out of the box support for using an http endpoint that didn't rely on SOAP. You had to accomplish that using a CustomBinding object and adding your own BindingElements. With 3.5 they came out with the WebHttpBinding to accomplish this. That's really what I meant. I apologize for not being as accurate \ clear as I could have been. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: hey thanks, fellas, it's all useful. FYI we do use some SOAP services in my org, but theyre pretty clunky, likely because in my enterprise environment everything is years behind the curve. this new project is a departure from that which is why im able to use VS '13, 4.5.1, and whatever else we've missed this decade :)

from the little overview i've found so far WCF SOAP does have some advantages w/ security, and isnt limited to HTTP, but for this project web is our only protocol. ill check it out.